# Using a whitelist too large for an AWS VPC Security Group

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, whitelist

I have a large list of IPs I need to whitelist for a VPC instance. I've added as many ranges as possible to the security group until I ran out of available rules. I'm adding rules for HTTP and HTTPS for each range, and I'm still left with about 100 individual IPs that I need to whitelist.

AFAIU I can't increase the rule limit for the security group, is there any other way I can whitelist the remaining IPs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put the additional rules in a second security group. Apply both groups to the instances - they're additive.

Comment: There seems to be a hard limit of around 250 eventually.

"... the multiple of the limit for inbound or outbound rules per security group and the limit for security groups per network interface cannot exceed 250"

Comment: The max number of security groups per EC2-vpc is 5, so this solution doesn't go far enough.

Comment: You can ask and have that limit raised IIRC